# Possible exeptions when uploading/downloading files to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: c#, exception, google-cloud-storage

I am using .NET `Google.Cloud.Storage.V1` library to upload and download files to and from Google Cloud Storage. I am interested in `Exception` handling. I know it is a bad practice to catch general `Exception` therefore I am trying to sort out what types of exceptions could I encounter. So far I have found these three:

1) `HttpRequestException` when something is wrong with connection

2) `OperationCanceledException` this might be thrown when connection is lost during started upload/download

3) `GoogleApiException`  when file does not exist in cloud, bucket is already existing, etc.

Is there anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: I guess you missed 

`System.Net.WebException` for responses like forbidden access etc;
`System.IO.IOException` while writing file locally you may run into disk storage and access issues

Comment: @zafar Thank you! I will add these to my code!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's "bad practice" because you typically only want to catch exceptions when you can do something about them. If you don't know what types of exceptions are thrown, what can you do to handle them?

The typical practice is to catch uncaught exceptions as high up the call stack as possible where you can do something more graceful than shutting down the process. For web apps this may mean redirecting to an error page, for forms it may be showing a message box, etc.

So if you are only catching exceptions to do general logging or something basic, there's nothing wrong with catching `Exception`.

To answer the actual question, .NET doesn't have metadata to indicate what exceptions could be thrown like Java or other platforms do. You'd have to rely on the documentation, if any. Plus, it would be an implementation detail that would be subject to change without breaking compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for answer! So dealing with all known specific cases, informing user, adding retry logic specific to each `Exception` type, etc, and at the end still catching general `Exception` just to log it, would be considered good practice? Also, I guess after logging it and notifying user I would still need to shut down the program since it is in unknown state?

Comment: It is not a good practice but you can catch the exceptions for general logging like that. You can also throw InvalidOperationException to indicate that an object has invalid state.